Python - Plotly Express - x axes xticks
I have a code that I want to plot x axis with labels as names of Month and Year.
But currently same code is plotting x axis differently for two data files. -

I want the x axis to be shown as seen in the top plot (Month and Year).
The bottom plot has all the timestamps plotted on the xticks which i do not want.
The code snippet is:
fig = px.scatter(data_frame, x=data_frame.timestamp, y=data_frame.err_codes_integer,
                    hover_name=data_frame.col3,
                    hover_data= {"size": False,
                                 "desc": True,
                                 "count": True},
                    title=(log_txt_files[idx]),
                    labels={"err_codes_integer": "error/event"} # y label
                    )
    fig.update_traces(showlegend=False,
                     marker = dict(size=data_frame['size'], symbol=data_frame['symbol'], color=data_frame['color'])
                     )
    fig.show()

How do I get just the names of Month and Year on the x axis instead of all the timestamps?
Thank you

I have created and reproduced the sample data to match your data. The correct x-axis display was as you intended. I ran it on the latest version of plotly, 5.23.0. What is your run version? Can you post that and reproducible data?

Any chance that the dates in the second plot aren't stored as date type? If it's reading it as character data, it's going to plot all unique values.
